# Environment variables to configure RabbitMQ

Tags: json, rabbitmq, erlang, kubernetes-helm

RabbitMQ can be configured using `definitions.json` and/or `advanced.config`. Is there a way to reference the Helm/Linux Environment Variables?

advanced.config excerpt:

````
    [{shovels,
      [%% A named shovel worker.
         {my_shovel,
          [
           {sources,
            [%% URI(s) and pre-declarations for all source broker(s).
             {brokers, [RMQ_URL]},
             {declarations, []}
            ]},```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your code into rabbitmq's bash start file, and replace variable with environment variable,